# How to create an optimiser to calculate amounts of ingredients in food products from nutrition and ingredient list only

Tags: python, optimization

I'd like to create an optimiser in Python that takes a list of ingredients and the nutritional value of the product, and outputs the amount of each ingredient in the product.

Examples of the ingredients and nutrition in these images:

[Ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53brx.png)

[Nutrition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErDRb.png)

The aim is to take the information in the two images (input manually, not read from the image) plus the nutritional value of each individual ingredient and output each ingredient's fraction of the total mass. Some of the ingredients already have their percentage of total mass listed, but I would be looking to do this for all ingredients.

What would be the best way to go about this? I'm fairly new to Python so am aiming for simplicity. Would an optimiser be the best place to start? Are there any packages that provide something that would be useful?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, you have chosen a rather difficult task to begin with. I would recommend going for solid basics before you start fiddling with a project that will include [text recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), string parsing and then some basic math. Every one of these is rather straightforward, with the text recognition being the biggest possible caveat(not that it is an easy topic, however the research was extensive and there are definitely some ready-to-use tools & libraries). However this is not the site to answer this kind of question.

Comment: However if you go for it and start solving this interesting-looking task, you will encounter many issues. When you research those, please do ask about them and I think that someone will be glad to help. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I actually intended to put in the ingredients manually, not the image itself. I guess that will make things easier

Comment: In that case it looks like a math excercise with percentages. Take the total mass of the product, divide by hundred, multiply by the listed percentage for the ingredient. Repeat for all ingredients that you will most likely want to store in the table beforehands. Bonus points for calculating the ratios of stuff like proteins, fats etc. from the listed ingredients. No optimizer necessarym that would be an overkill.

Comment: Unfortunately not all the ingredients have percentages listed. Otherwise indeed I could just calculate them easily!

Comment: Not sure why you would use an optimizer to solve that problem. What is there to optimize? The fraction of total mass is fixed (but unknown) for each ingredient, right? So the optimizer would have no room to "choose" (or optimize) anything.

Comment: I was imagining that it would do something like guess the unknown fractions, calculate the resulting total calories, and then compare with the known total calories. It would minimise the difference between these two by adjusting and recalculating. How were you thinking it could be done?